# restore only last 1 or 2 months data in sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 5 TB of data in production and my development team requested to restore only last month data(<=500 MB ) in staging server and last 2 months data in pre production.

How can I restore only last 1 or 2 months data in sqlserver?

Comment: This site only allows you to accept **one** answer, you can upvote the others if you have a 15+ reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible to restore the data for only the last few months even if you have timestamp field in all  your tables as that would lead you to some inconsistent data.

Comment: Thanks Rahul for immediate respons but we need to have it because client is also suggesting (since they are already implemented when they were having contract with another company) to have the data in this format and will they verify once the data is restored.

Comment: @Franklin:- The only think which I can think of is to slice the data but I dont think that there is full proof method which SQL Server provides.

Comment: Folks any ideas or suggestions on my  question ?